# UI Bootstrap tabset content size larger than the menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

```
<div id="Menu-Large" class="span12 hidden-phone">
            <tabset class="span8">
                <tab heading="Home">
                    @RenderSection("featured", false)
                </tab>
                <tab heading="Contact">
                    @RenderPage("~/Views/Home/Contact.cshtml")
                </tab>
            </tabset>
        </div>
```

Above is my code for the menu I am trying to create using UI Bootstrap, AngluarJS, ASP.NET MVC4.

My issue is that I want the Menu to be only span8 long.. but the content within it to be `span12` long.

Is there anyway I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so i know this is late but I solved it by putting layering the tabset inside another div with the class row

```
<div class="row">
```